# Google Cloud Vision API DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION returning incorrect bounding box

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION" option from the Google Cloud Vision API.

It seems that it's returning correct text value, but incorrect coordinates bounding box.

Why this problem occurred?

Thank you.

### raw picture

[image]

### draw bounding box picture

[image]

### returning [json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/namagon/03559df48688822e891c2f7e74220f0f/raw/e96eb45916a76fbb2ecc132735cfd7563ea7246c/gistfile1.txt)

---

## appendix

### draw bounding box words and overall

[image]

Comment: Are the word-level bounding boxes in the wrong places too, or just the character-level bounding boxes?

Comment: @rmtheis Sorry for replying so late. Please check appendix. Thank you.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue.  Even when I use the demo it doesn't seem to have the bounding boxes correctly set around the translated text. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop   What is the alternative to using "TEXT_DETECTION " ?

Answer (score 0):

The DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION is meant for dense text, I recommend to use the [TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) for that image.

Comment: Clearly the user used this google cloud platform image as a mock example. Even if the user provides dense text image, google vision bounding boxes are not properly aligned neither at the character level nor word level.

Answer (score 0):

I use DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION model and I have the same problem.

The symbol level bounding boxes are very offset, overlapping other symbols.
And this even though the OCR did a good job and was able to find a matching character...
See attached picture for illustration. (OCR result is perfect in this straightforward situation):

[image]

I notice this model have become legacy as per https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes#May_15_2020, maybe the replacement does a better job at this.